# Intellij suggestion is not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just installed `IntelliJ` and I realized the auto suggestion is not working. I have worked with eclipse and there it automatically pops out all the methods for a instance variable but here I didn't see that happening. I checked all the preference and it seems to be fine.

[image: No suggestion]
[image: Options]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **can't** call a method outside of a block (*methods/static blocks/instance blocks/etc : anything between balanced braces*) in java.

It won't/shouldn't work in eclipse either.

> **Block** is a group of zero or more statements between balanced braces
>   and can be used anywhere a single statement is allowed.

Check for more about [Expressions, Statements, and Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)